# How to reverse the Stack?

Tags: algorithm, scala, stack

May be it is too easy question but Please share how to reverse any kind of stack?

Comment: Have you tried `stack.reverse`?

Comment: if you are refering to the immutable version, then it´s just a `List`, so reverse works.

Comment: This is homework, isn't it?  You should add the homework tag.

Comment: Use a double linked list. Then you can pop and push to either end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't speak Scala, but [according to the doc you simply call `reverse` on the stack](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stack.html).

Answer (score 12):

The right answer may be "don't reverse a stack."

If some constraint means you absolutely have to reverse a stack, your question is already answered.  But, I can't help but wonder *why* you want to reverse a stack --  to me, that means you are using the wrong data structure.

If its all pushes, then the reverse, then all pops; thats a queue.

If pushes, pops, and reverses are mixed in random order, you probably want a data structure that specifically supports those operations... it will be confusing when someone reads "stack" but the structure is really something else.

Not sure about scala, but some languages have a double-ended queue to specifically represent a linear collection with access to the head and tail elements -- that may be exactly what you need.  If not, a doubly-linked list will do nicely; or a plain old list will do if an O(n) `pop()`-equivalent isn't an issue.

If your `pop()` equivalent operation isn't aware of which end to get an element from (e.g., one piece of code is calling reverse, and some other code just says "give me an element" and isn't aware of whether or not reverse has been called), encapsulate the queue with a flag for direction as follows.  This will give you the same functionality without having to actually reverse anything.

(sorry for the very-pseudo code, scala isn't in my toolbox).

```
ReversableStack {
    DoublyLinkedList backingStore;
    Boolean forward;

    get() {
        if (forward) return backingStore.take_head();
        else return backingStore.take_tail();
    }

    put(item) {
        if (forward) backingStore.add_head(item);
        else backingStore.add_tail(item);
    }

    reverse() {
        forward = !forward;
    }
}
```

Comment: "don't reverse a stack." -- quite true. Sadly, both `Stack` and `Queue` extend standard collection traits in Scala.

Answer (score 8):

```
make new stack;
while (old stack not empty)
    x = pop(old stack)
    push x on new stack
```

Or call `reverse` on the stack, but note that that returns a `List` if applied to a `mutable.Stack`. It does return a `Stack` if you use `immutable.Stack`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void reverse(Stack st) { 
    int m = (int)st.Pop(); 
    if (st.Count != 1) 
        reverse(st); 
    Push(st , m); 
} 

public void Push(Stack st , int a) { 
    int m = (int)st.Pop(); 
    if (st.Count != 0) 
        Push(st , a); 
    else 
        st.Push(a); 
    st.Push(m); 
}
```

Comment: This does not work *in-place*. It uses O(N) additional memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop around popping values from it and pushing them into another stack.